# Solr - Polygon Search - Sort results from center of the polygon by distance

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud, bounding-box

We were previously using Lucene 4 core api, and recently moved to SolrCloud v 7.7.X.

I have the following field definition for doing spatial queries for polygons -

```
 <fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               spatialContextFactory="JTS"
               autoIndex="true"
               validationRule="repairBuffer0"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.001"
               geo="true" 
               distanceUnits="kilometers" />
```

and here is my field definition -

```
 <field name="LATLON" multiValued="true" type="location_rpt" indexed="true"/>
```

And here is my sample query -

```
q=*:*&fq={!field f=LATLON}Intersects(POLYGON(( -74.31737 40.61442, -73.48103 40.61442, -73.48103 41.24627, -74.31737 41.24627, -74.31737 40.61442)))&fq=TYPE:HOTEL&cache=true&fl=*,score&debug=false&rows=2000
```

The results are not returned in any particular order, but I want them to be always returned based on the center of the polygon by distance.

What are we missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use geofilt method something like this

```
fq= "{!geofilt pt=" + latLng + " sfield=geoBoundary d=" + distance.get + " sort=geodist(geoBoundary," + latLng + ") asc}")
```

- `latlng = your location point`
- `geoBoundary = your polygon`

Comment: So based on above, the query is translating to -
```fq={!geofilt pt=LATLON sfield=Intersects(POLYGON((-74.31737 40.61442,-73.48103 40.61442, -73.48103 41.24627, -74.31737 41.24627, -74.31737 40.61442))) d=distance.get sort=geodist(Intersects(POLYGON((-74.31737 40.61442,-73.48103 40.61442, -73.48103 41.24627, -74.31737 41.24627, -74.31737 40.61442))), LATLON) asc}```
Is this correct, it is giving me the following error root-error-class","org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError

Comment: And what is the need for the distance in the case of polygon, I am looking to get points within the polygon.

Comment: i guess there is other way to do it using geoDist method which is used for sorting https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-geodist

Comment: Uttkarsh - do you use specify your 4 latlon positions using this?

Comment: @jagamot I dint get you. could you put the question in other way